# puppeteer can't get page source after using evaluate()

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to interact with a website using the evaluate() function to maniupulate page front (i.e to click on certain items etc...), click through works fine but I can't return the page source after clicking using evaluate.

I have recreated the error in this simplified script below it loads google.com, clicks on 'I feel lucky' and should then return the page source of the loaded page:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

    response = await page.evaluate(() => {
            document.getElementsByClassName('RNmpXc')[1].click()
        });

    await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'});

    console.log(response.text());

}

main();
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

**UPDATE** New code following suggestion to use page.content()

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

    await page.evaluate(() => {
            document.getElementsByClassName('RNmpXc')[1].click()
        });

    const source = await page.content()
    console.log(source);

}

main();
```

I am now getting the following error:

```
Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.
```

My question is: How can I return page source using the .text() method after manipulating the webpage using the evaluate() method?

All suggestions / insight / proposals would be very much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're asking for page source after javascript modification, I'd assume you want DOM and not the original HTML content. your `evaluate` function doesn't return anything which results in undefined response. You can use

```js
const source = await page.evaluate(() => new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.doctype) + document.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

or

```js
const source = await page.content();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input, I've tried integrating your suggestions to my code but i'm still facing the following error "Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation." Have a look I've updated my question to reflect the changes in my code. oh and serialize returns the same error aswell. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mikemeyers you need to wait for the navigation after clicking using `waitForNavigation` and then get the content

Comment: Yep thanks i just found that out while searching the official puppeteer github. The issue i'am facing now is that not all sources are returned. Meaning, that using page.content() or serializing, the CSS is incomplete and the javascript doesnt work on the returned page source. Got anymore tricks up your sleeve to solve this?

Comment: @mikemeyers can you elaborate? `page.content` doesn't download a website and its content, it returns the DOM.

Comment: Sure, when I retrieve the page.content, the DOM seems incomplete or perhaps broken. I have tried re-rendering the retrieved page.content in a browser and the JS of the rendered page doesn't work. I gotta say thanks for your time you've been really helpful.

Comment: @mikemeyers that does not work because you're loading from a local file. run a web server and serve the DOM (or the original html) and then visit it and you'll see resources loading fine.

Comment: Yeah i thought so aswell, so I gave it a try,but as it turns out all sources that are not absolute paths are obviously not being rendered. So we're talking CSS, and any JS where the src="" tag points to a relative path. Any suggestions of how i can work around this issue. I guess I could parse through entire page.content() returned source and replace the site root wherever its needed but that woud cost some serious computational overhead and slow thing down alot. Any suggesstions?

Comment: @mikemeyers you can use [base](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag for solving that.